# CASE WHEN from a nested CASE WHEN without subquery?

Tags: sql, pivot, case, aggregate-functions

This creates a segment of if an order had 2+ Units:

`CASE WHEN SUM(quantity) > 1 then '2+ Units' ELSE '1 Unit' END as qty_flag_total`

I want to create additional versions that only count particular product categories, so only the quantity for product 'bike' is summed.

I have this to SUM the quantity only for product 'bike':

`SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'bike' THEN quantity END) AS qty_bike`

But wondering if there's a clean way to create the same flag on top of this for whether the quantity is either '1 unit' or '2+ units'?

I only know it making the above in a subquery, that the 2+ unit flag CASE then uses, but want to do it all from the base table if possible.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'bike' THEN quantity END) > 1
    THEN '2+ Bike Units'
    ELSE '1 Bike Unit'
END AS qty_flag_bike
```

You might also want to handle the case when there is no bike unit at all:

```
CASE SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'bike' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END)
    WHEN 0 then 'No Bike Unit'
    WHEN 1 then '1 Bike Unit'
    ELSE '2+ Bike Units'
END AS qty_flag_bike
```

Comment: Actually I'm having some trouble with it for handling nulls in the nested sum() case when. When that is null, it's defaulting to the '2+ Units' ELSE statement. But I'm not able to add another WHEN clause for >1  because it's not letting me use the > operator